# I have a piece of code that only works for numbers greater than 1000. Any explanation why?

Tags: python

I've been using this piece of code to make random names and grades of students for a project that I'm working on, but when I only want 100 names to be made instead of 1000, nothing happens to the text file that I write to.

```
from random import randint

file = open("rawgrade.txt", "w")

# Create the list of all the letters in the alphabet to easily select from
alphalist = []

for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    alphalist.append(letter)

# Create random people and grades for the test file
for i in range(100): # only works for 1000 and up in my trials  

    # Create the random name of the person
    namelen = randint(1, 16)
    namestr = ""

    for j in range(namelen):
        randomletter = randint(0,25)

        namestr += alphalist[randomletter]

    # Create the random grade for the person
    grade = randint(0, 100)

    # Write to file
    file.write(namestr + " " + str(grade) + "\n")
```

Comment: I don't know when you look at the file or what happens between reaching the end of the program shown here and the underlying process, but it seems to me that the missing `file.close()` could be the root of the problem.

Comment: @glglgl Exiting the script should close all files.

Comment: works fine for me too. You should also use `with` to open your files as it  will also close them.

Comment: @Barmar Exiting the *process* should close the files. If we run this in some weird framework, it could be that the script is done, but the process goes on running.

Comment: @glglgl not if it's run inside of the python repl or ipython.

Comment: @glglgl That explains why it works when I run `python scriptname.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your file when you're done. Otherwise the results are unpredictable:

```
file.close()
```

(If you're running in the repl or ipython, then the file may not "close itself" until you quit.)

But there are lots of other very non-Pythonic aspects to your code which I don't have time to go over right now!... A short sample:

- Don't use "file" as a name since it's already a built-in.
- Don't bother making `alphalist` as you can index the string.
- Open and close using `with`

For fun, here's what I think is a much better version:

```
from random import randint, choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

num_students = 100
max_name_len = 16

with open("rawgrade.txt", "w") as fil:

    # Create random people and grades for the test file
    for i in range(num_students):  

        # Create the random name of the person
        ### this can probably be made simpler....
        namelen = randint(1, max_name_len)
        namestr = ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for j in range(namelen)])

        # Create the random grade for the person
        grade = randint(0, 100)

        # Write to file
        fil.write(namestr + " " + str(grade) + "\n")
```

Comment: Normally no, but under certain circumstances you could be right.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is actually the right answer! (I tested it.)

Comment: I think it's unpredictable exactly when iPython will close the file.